# SQL remove duplicates from a single table based on a few of the selected columns

Tags: sql

I came across an interesting situation on what I hope can be solved by a simple query... but I cannot manage to form the query...

```
table    
node trigger value date
A    A3      5     2016-01-12 00:00:00
A    A1      4     2016-01-12 00:00:00
B    B2      3     2016-01-12 01:00:00
A    A3      1     2016-01-13 00:00:00
```

- Display the latest occurring trigger on each node with corresponding value in the table above.
- *node* and *trigger* should be sorted in alphabetical order

This is the closest I have come to a query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(node, trigger), value 
FROM table 
ORDER BY node, trigger, date DESC;
```

I want DISTINCT to execute on the *node*/*trigger* pairs. More than one *node*/*trigger* pair is displayed as they have different *value*, i.e. not unique and therefore not removed by DISTINCT. Adding GROUP BY doesn't seems to help. The answer on the query on the table above should be like this...

```
node trigger value 
A    A1      4    
A    A3      1     
B    B2      3
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function, and trigger is a reserved word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL groupwise MAX() returns unexpected results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613187/mysql-groupwise-max-returns-unexpected-results)

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL then the correct syntax is `DISTINCT ON (node, trigger)`. If not, then which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I generally create a subset with the max data value from the base table thus creating a set of just max dates and nodes.  Then join back to base set to get the rest of the needed values.

In this case I created an inline view which is the set having max dates for each node.

```
SELECT A.node, A.trigger, A.value
FROM table A
INNER JOIN (Select node, max(date) as MDate From Table GROUP BY node) B
  on B.Node = A.Node
 and B.MDate = A.Date 
ORDER BY A.Node, A.Tigger
```

Depending on rdbms, trigger column may need to be escaped. using rdbms method

Distinct will not work

Answer (score 0):

This will give you distinct even if dates are equal works in SQL-Server at least

```
SELECT t.node, t.[trigger], (SELECT TOP 1 value from [Table] t2 where t2.node=t.node and t2.[trigger]=t.[trigger] order by [date] desc)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT node, [trigger]
FROM  [Table]) as t
```