# joining two table with first row of first table and last row of second table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mysql

personal_details

```
reg_id    fname    lname    mobile  
   1        x      y        9999999999  
   2        m      n        8888888888  
   3        a      b        7777777777
```

education_details

```
edu_id   reg_id    qualification  
  1        1         High-school  
  2        1         Intermediate   
  3        2         High-school  
  4        2         Intermediate   
  5        2         B.A  
  6        3         High-school
```

Result, i want is

```
   
reg_id   fname  lname      mobile       qualification  
  1         x     y        999999999    Intermediate  
  2         m     n        888888888    B.A  
  3         a     b        777777777    High-school
```

I have tried a lot but not getting accurate result

I tried so far:

```
SELECT a.reg_id, a.fname, a.lname, a.mobile, b.qualification 
FROM personal_details a, education_details b 
WHERE a.reg_id = b.reg_id 
GROUP BY b.qualification
```

Comment: "I have tried a lot" Ok, what did you tried. Can you give some examples?

Comment: SELECT a.reg_id, a.fname, a.lname, a.mobile,  b.qualification 
FROM personal_details a, education_details b
WHERE a.reg_id = b.reg_id
GROUP BY b.qualification

Comment: Consider update your question with this kind of details, so new reader can see the current state of the question without reading all comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL groupwise MAX() returns unexpected results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613187/mysql-groupwise-max-returns-unexpected-results)

Answer (score 0):

use `join`

```
    select * from personal_details p
    right join education_details e
    on p.reg_id=e.reg_id
    where edu_id=
(select max(edu_id) from education_details pnew where pnew.edu_id=p.edu_id)
```

Comment: There is no edu_id column in personal_details table

Comment: It's odd that you recommend join (a good idea BTW) and then don't use it.

Comment: @Strawberry, can you give me more idea about query you are telling about.